# Creating coupon through API and ruby returns error: woocommerce_api_missing_coupon_data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create a coupon though the rest api from my rails 4 app using the sample code from the documentation on this page: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?ruby#create-a-coupon

Here is the code I am using:

```
 data = {
      code: "10off",
      discount_type: "percent",
      amount: "10",
      individual_use: true,
      exclude_sale_items: true,
      minimum_amount: "100.00"
    }
woocommerce.post("coupons", data).parsed_response
```

I expect it to return a successful response from the API instead I get `{"errors"=>[{"code"=>"woocommerce_api_missing_coupon_data", "message"=>"No coupon data specified to create coupon"}]}`

Comment: First try the request using curl instead of code, it may be server misconfiguration as well

Comment: I have updated my answer below after some research.

Comment: Have you tried using the coupon key within data? Could you solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paragraph below shows how it was working, at least in API V2 and V3.

The params / data hash contained a coupon attribute, see [v3 documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#create-a-coupon):

```
data = {
  coupon: {
    code: "new-coupon"
    ...
  }
}
```

After some research, I am still not sure that the example in the API description is right, as you can see [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/c63cd802aa149f8f91b33e287aa8d67eb50eab12/includes/legacy/api/v3/class-wc-api-coupons.php#L208).

The code below is available for V2 and V3 and there is no other code available, V3 was updated 13 days ago. The error is raised when 'coupon' is not available in data:

```
if ( ! isset( $data['coupon'] ) ) {
 throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_missing_coupon_data', sprintf( __( 'No %1$s data specified to create %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), 'coupon' ), 400 );
}
```

I suggest trying with this code:

```
data = {
  coupon: {
      code: "10off",
      discount_type: "percent",
      amount: "10",
      individual_use: true,
      exclude_sale_items: true,
      minimum_amount: "100.00"
  }
}
woocommerce.post("coupons", data).parsed_response
```

If this works I would stick to the [V3 documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3?ruby#create-a-coupon) for the time being or raise an issue e.g. by creating a ticket with Woocommerce. Maybe their documentation team worked faster than development :)

Comment: Thanks for your response trying this today